# Reader issue with JCOP applet upload

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I have successfully worked with JCOP Tools in combination with SCM SDI 010 Reader for quite a while. When I tried to change my Card Reader now, I noticed that with other Readers(for example SCM SCL 011) the upload command failed (GP Install for Load) with Response 6D00:

```
cm>  upload -d "xxx.cap"
```

> => 80 E6 02 00 13 06 64 65 2E 62 64 72 08 A0 00 00
>       01 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>    (29683 usec)
>
> <= 6D 00

Status: INS value not supported

I have tried a lot, but without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: To rule out the basics... explicitly selecting the card manager plus establishing a secure channel works?

Comment: yes that worked, upload command immediatly failed on the first apdu